# How to make pic upload seen immediately

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, ionic4

I'm creating an Ionic app that allows users to upload pics to Firebase storage.
The problem I'm having is that it's only changing the pic when a new one is selected after I close the app and re-open. I'd like it to change immediately upon upload.  And when it's deleted, immediately revert back to the place holder pic.

It's working but you can only see the pic after closing the app and re-opening the page.

TypeScript:

```
    constructor(private router: Router,
              private authService: AuthService,
              private imageService: ImageService,
              private afAuth: AngularFireAuth) {

      this.afAuth.authState.subscribe(user => {
      this.userId = user.uid
      console.log('constructoruser', this.userId);
      });
              }

  ngOnInit() {
          this.firestore.ref(`/Photos/${ this.userId }/`).child('photo0').getDownloadURL().then((url) => {
          this.photo0 = url;
        }).catch((error) => {
          console.log(error.message);
          this.photo0 = 'assets/img/add-an-image.png';
          console.log(this.photo0);
        });
  }
```

HTML:

```
<div>
    <img [src]="photo0" (click)="UploadPic0('photo0')"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the code snippet you shared (**not included UploadPic0 method**), this is happening because you are setting image from the url only once during component initialization (**ngOnInit**, which is called only once).

Now the possible solution:
 - Create a new method that will update the image(to either image url or the fallback image)
 - call this method in ngOnInit and when ever you get a success/failure message regarding image upload.
 - As a failsafe (to make sure the render method is called once image is updated), call the change detector.

something like

```
updateImage() {
        this.firestore.ref(`/Photos/${this.userId}/`).child('photo0').getDownloadURL().then((url) => {
         this.photo0 = url;
        }).catch((error) => {
          console.log(error.message);
          this.photo0 = 'assets/img/add-an-image.png';
        });
}
```